# Как привязать вызов метода одного объекта к вызову метода другого объекта средствами C++17 и stdlib?

Tags: c++

Необходимо обрабатывать события, происходящие в одном объекте, с помощью методов другого объекта, причём первый объект не должен как-то зависеть от второго. Сейчас есть реализация, описанная ниже. Но в ней есть существенный недостаток, необходимо вручную заменять все аргументы методов с помощью std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, ..., std::placeholders::_N. Возможно ли как-то переписать функцию connect, чтобы не требовалось заменять все аргументы методов, а вызывать её так connect(a.event1, b, &B::handler1)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class A {
public:
    std::function<void(int)> event1{[](int){}};
    std::function<void(int,int)> event2{[](int,int){}};
};

class B {
public:
    void handler1(int value) {
        std::cout << "B: " << value << std::endl;
    }
};

class C {
public:
    void handler2(int value1, int value2) {
        std::cout << "C: " << value1 << " " << value2 << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class R, class E, class H, class... Types>
void connect(E& event, R& receiver, H handler, Types... args) {
    event = std::bind(handler, &receiver, args...);
}

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    connect(a.event1, b, &B::handler1, std::placeholders::_1);
    connect(a.event2, c, &C::handler2, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

    // The handler1 method of object b must be called
    a.event1(42);
    // The handler2 method of object c must be called
    a.event2(42, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Почему бы не воспользоваться виртуальными функциями и хранить вместо `std::function` указатель на соотв. интерфейс, который реализуют другие классы?

Comment: @user7860670 так не получается, потому что некоторые события одного объекта нужно обрабатывать в разных объектах, как показано в примере.

Comment: Ничего не мешает  некоторые события одного объекта обрабатывать в разных объектах посредством виртуальных функций.

Comment: @user7860670 можно небольшой пример, как это сделать?

Comment: ¿Ну а что тут непонятного? Пусть один объект реализует интерфейс для первого события, второй - для второго.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл способ не указывать аргументы с помощью std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, и т. д., для этого нужно использовать лямбду с автоматическим выводом аргументов

```
template<class R, class E, class H>
void connect(E& event, R& receiver, H handler) {
    event = [&receiver, handler](auto... args) { (receiver.*handler)(args...); };
}
```

Обновление: @HolyBlackCat предложил более правильный вариант функции connect, учитывающий перемещение ссылки на обработчик события, правильную подстановку аргументов в случае некопируемых типов и ссылок и оптимизацию в случае копируемых типов.

```
template<class R, class E, class H>
void connect(E& event, R& receiver, H &&handler) {
    event = [&receiver, handler = std::forward<H>(handler)](auto &&... args) {
        (receiver.*handler)(decltype(args)(args)...);
    };
}
```

Comment: Правильнее так: `event = [&receiver, handler = std::move(handler)](auto &&... args) { (receiver.*handler)(decltype(args)(args)...); };`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat почему правильнее, если можно, поясните, по элементам `handler = std::move(handler)`, `(auto &&... args)`, `(decltype(args)(args)...)`?

Comment: `decltype(args)(args)...` - это примерно как `std::forward`. Если бы там было `T &&... args`, написал бы `std::forward<T>(args)...`, но тут `auto`, поэтому тип никак не получить без `decltype`. А если мы используем `decltype`, то `forward` можно не писать (это то же самое, что `std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...`, но короче).

Comment: Про `handler` - это чтобы не копировать его. Дешевле переместить. Но я немного не то посоветовал - еще быстрее было бы `H &&handler`, а потом `handler = std::forward<H>(handler)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat тоесть это просто оптимизации?

Comment: Когда как. Если у обработчика параметры - некопируемые типы или ссылки, то ваш вариант не скомпилируется (для некопируемых типов) или будет работать неправильно (со ссылками). Если копируемые - то да, просто оптимизация.